# Tracking progress of 7zip command line to create a zip archive

Tags: 7-zip

I will be running 7Zip from node.js as a command line batch job. Is there a way to track the progress, (i.e. to read the progress meter (20% OF 100%) either by reading the output stream, or any other way so that I can forward this to a user.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found one can get incremental progress from the command line (no GUI). Try the -bsp1 switch: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/bs.htm

However, a better way to create and track a zip archive creation is probably to use a npm package called archiver (https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/issues/147) which does not need to do context switching, or reading of the output stream, to track, and my testing shows it runs at the same or better speed than 7zip.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: the other  question was how to track the progress of the extract, this question was mine how to track the progress of the zip create

Comment: That doesn't matter. Different questions can have the same answer - and are therefore duplicates.